# Cgo ignores CXXFLAGS -std=c++11 option

Tags: go, cgo

I have a golang app that includes a C header (a wrapper for C++ code that calls C++ class methods) and a static library that contains object files corresponding to this header.
When I built the app I got this error:

> c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: This file requires compiler and library
> support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled
> with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
> #error This file requires compiler and library support

This is my cgo preamble:

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lpoly_c -lstdc++
// #cgo darwin LDFLAGS: -framework Accelerate
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/x86_64-apple-darwin21/
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/x86_64-apple-darwin21/
// #include "poly_c.h"
import "C"

...
```

I'm not sure why `#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11` doesn't work here. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Full output of `go build -x`:

> ➜ go build -x cmd/poly/main.go
>   WORK=/var/folders/9b/6wtsv5gd1kq4g6p47kl_1h_d05yb_r/T/go-build2252443246
>   mkdir -p $WORK/b042/
>   cd /Users/upv/dev/voicestream/service/poly
>   TERM='dumb' CGO_LDFLAGS='"-O2" "-g" "-lpoly_c" "-lstdc++" "-framework" "Accelerate"' /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/cgo -objdir $WORK/b042/ -importpath
>   github.com/upvs/voicestream/poly -- -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/x86_64-apple-darwin21/ -I $WORK/b042/ -O2 -g ./poly.go
>   # github.com/upvs/voicestream/poly
>   In file included from poly/poly.go:11:
>   In file included from ./poly_c.h:2:
>   In file included from ./poly.hpp:3:
>   In file included from ./irapt_fast_lib.h:4:
>   In file included from ./general_types.h:4:
>   In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/cinttypes:35:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/include/c++/13/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
>   #error This file requires compiler and library support \
>    ^
>   1 error generated.